# AngularJS - Dynamic parameter in $http URL

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

The URL I use to retreive a `JSON` for my app has a dynamic parameter (**:id** ). I'm not too sure how I can work with this, so that it passes the ID the user has chosen. Just need a bit of guidance.

```
app.factory('bookcategories', ['$http', function($http) {
  return $http.get('http://52.41.65.211:8028/api/v1/categories/:id/books.json')
    .success(function(data) {
        return data;
    })
    .error(function(err) {
        return err;
  });
}]);
```

**Controller**

```
app.controller('BookCategoryController', ['$scope', 'categories', '$routeParams',  function($scope, categories, $routeParams) {
    categories.success(function(data) {
    $scope.detail = data.categories[$routeParams.bookId];
    $scope.currentCategoryIndex = parseInt($routeParams.categoryId);

        $scope.myCategoriesDetails = $scope.category;
    });
}]);
```

**app.js**

```
...
  .when('/categories/:categoryId', {
    controller: 'BookCategoryController',
    templateUrl: 'views/booksincategory.html'
})
...
```

**HTML**

```
<h3 class="title">{{book.title}}</h3>
```

Comment: A factory is supposed to return an object, which has methods that the users of the service can call. Your factory directly calls $http and returns a promise.

Comment: `bookcategories` should be a service. Btw. `bookcategories` is never used in your codes?

Comment: Use1937021, I see you don't like to mark "right answers". Please check all your questions and mark right answers. Thanks

Comment: Thanks m8, please check your other questions and mark right answers please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could achieve this with a little service like the following code example. A factory is a wrong choice here.

```
app.service('bookCategories', ['$http', function($http) {
  this.get = function (id) {
      return $http.get('http://52.41.65.211:8028/api/v1/categories/'+ id + '/books.json')
        .success(function(data) {
          return data;
        })
        .error(function(err) {
          return err;
        });
  };
}]);
```

And than use it like:

```
app.controller('MyCtrl', function(bookCategories) {
  bookCategories.get(1).then(function (result) {
    console.log(result);
  });
});
```

Comment: *A factory is a wrong choice here* and yet the code you posted is actually a factory disguised as a service. A real service would initialize `this`, and wouldn't return anything.